# What is the fastest way to import data from application (Java) into temporary table?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am developing an application with Java, Spring and PostgreSQL. I am using Spring-JDBC as database layer.

In my Java application, I have around 10.000 rows which need to be inserted in a temporary table. What is the fastest way to import them?

I already tried:

```
create temporary table my_table on commit drop;

with data as (values (...), (...), ...) -- all 10.000 rows enumerated
insert into my_table select * from data;
```

But this fails because the query becomes too big to parse.

Should I simply send smaller batches, or is there a more clever approach for streaming data to the database?

**update**

What I am doing:

In the database, there is a table with, let's say, 'external entities'. Every few hours, I get an update (via ActiveMQ broker) with the complete current set of entities. This set needs to be in my database. I do the following:

- insert into temporary table
- copy new entities from temporary table to actual table
- delete old entities from actual table
- update changed entities in actual table

I cannot simple truncate my actual table and insert directly into the actual table, because of foreign constraints to that table and triggers on that table. In other words, I am only reflecting the actual changes.

Comment: @Marvin, I will add this to my description.

Comment: Meanwhile, maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311042/different-ways-of-performing-bulk-insert-into-database-from-a-java-application?rq=1

Comment: Can you process the "external entities" in memory and e.g. only add the new entries directly to the actual table?

Comment: does n't it support `copy from stdin`?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `copy from stdin`. It would be the smartest and the fastest way to put 10K rows

http://pgpen.blogspot.ie/2013/05/using-copy-in-your-jdbc-code.html