# Inserting multiple records from a List<Person> into Oracle DB?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Assuming we have a Person class with setters and getters that pertain to its attributes of:

```
private int age
private String name
private String address
private double weight //lbs
private double height //cm
```

And then a list of them as such:

```
Person person1 = new Person(18, "Jack Harrs", "55 Albridge St", 155.20, 167.53)
Person person2 = new Person(53, "Toby Canes", "59 Albridge St", 193.43, 179.11)
Person person3 = new Person(24, "Dwayne Right", "74 W Saint St", 183.22, 183.87)
Person person4 = new Person(33, "Shelby Johnson", "99 Broad St", 123.50, 158.30)

List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
personsList.add(person1);
personsList.add(person2);
personsList.add(person3);
personsList.add(person4);
```

Is there a way to build a SQL statement that inserts all of them into an Oracle DB? I was thinking it should look like:

```
INSERT INTO persons_table (AGE, NAME, ADDRESS, WEIGHT, HEIGHT, REGISTRATION_DATE) 
VALUES (18, "Jack Harrs", "55 Albridge St", 155.20, 167.53, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       (53, "Toby Canes", "59 Albridge St", 193.43, 179.11, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       (24, "Dwayne Right", "74 W Saint St", 183.22, 183.87, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
       (33, "Shelby Johnson", "99 Broad St", 123.50, 158.30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

But this does not work and I don't know how to build the SQL statement in Java for it to look like that even. I have read something about a batch insert but I don't know how to do that as well since this is very few times working with databases. If possible, could I request 2 ways to do it, one with a single single query (if possible) and one with a batch insert?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different ways of performing bulk insert into database from a java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311042/different-ways-of-performing-bulk-insert-into-database-from-a-java-application)

Comment: Is there a way for it to add multiple with just 1 SQL query instead of using a for loop to create multiple?

Comment: that's what `executeBatch` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain JDBC you could do something like this:

```
Connection con = ... //get it from somewhere

//prepare the statement
PreparedStatement stmt = con .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persons_table (AGE, NAME, ADDRESS, WEIGHT, HEIGHT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

//add a batch for each person
for( Person person : personsList ) {
  stmt.setInt(1, person.getAge());
  stmt.setString(2, person.getName());
  stmt.setString(3, person.getAddress());
  stmt.setDouble(4, person.getWeight());
  stmt.setDouble(5, person.getHeight());
  stmt.addBatch();
}

//execute the batch and get results for each query in the order they have been added
int[] results = stmt.executeBatch();
```

**Edit**:

As per request, here's how you could filter the persons that got inserted. Note that you'd still need to read the documentation of status codes that your driver might return especially in special cases but let's assume we get `1` for a successfully inserted person and `-3` (see `PreparedStatement.EXECUTE_FAILED`) for a failed insert:

```
List<Person> insertedPersons = new ArrayList<>();

for( int i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
  int status = results[i];

  if( status == 1 ) { //or any other status that represents success
    insertedPersons.add(personsList.get(i));
  }
}
```

**Edit**: `executeBatch()` might actually throw a `BatchUpdateExeption` if one of the statements fails. This also exception contains an array of results in the same order as the statements but depending on the driver execution might stop at the first exception and the array might just contain the status up to the exception point.

The approach above would still work but you might change the call like this:

```
int[] results;
try { 
  results = stmt.executeBatch();
} catch(BatchUpdateException e) { 
  results = e.getUpdateCounts();
}

//in some cases the exception might return null if execution failed right away so initialize to an empty array to prevent a NPE
if( results == null ) {
  results = new int[0];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to return the List<Persons> that got added to the DB after inserting them succesfully?

Comment: @stackerstack Sure, you'd basically need to iterate over `results` and check for the value (in your case that value should be 1 if the insert happened but please check the documentation again). Since indices match you'd then know which persons have been added and which failed, i.e. if you get something like `[1,-3,1]` you'd know that persons at index 0 and 2 in your list have been inserted successfully. Then just filter accordingly.

Comment: Could you pretty please possibly provide that in the code mentioned above? 

So you're saying that results could return the actual list<person> that got inserted? It doesn't seem clear to me right now because it's just an integer array so I don't know how i could get the list<person> that got inserted successfully from it

Comment: I see the updated post, thank you. Lets say that every column in the DB is a primary key. If we try to insert 5 people, and 2 of those people are duplicates what would the int[] result look like? Wouldn't it just throw a SQL database unique keys error instead of returning -3 in the array?

Comment: @stackerstack well that depends on the JDBC driver and probably on the database as well. You'd need to check the documentation or just try it.

Comment: @stackerstack you might also have a look at the JavaDoc of `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()`. In case of a duplicate you might get a `BatchUpdateException` which you'd want to catch and then call `getUpdateCounts()` as your results array. The semantics is still the same but the array might just contain the status code for statements that were successful up to the duplicate (the method I showed should still work in that case). Whether execution stops at the first duplicate or tries to execute all depends on the driver, however.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this solution worked nicely so of course i'm going to give you a check. But could you please include in the solution, instead of returning ```int[] results``` to return a boolean true or false indicating whether the operation was successful or not?

Comment: @stackerstack I'm not sure what you want me to include. JDBC has a certain interface which I can't change and my answer doesn't include anything on "returning" from the method where you call JDBC. Mapping the `int[]` to a boolean should be straight forward though, once you decided what success would mean: Do all results have to indicate success? Or is it already successful if just one of the batch inserts was successful?

Answer (score -1):

For oracle one of the way to insert multiple rows is below:

```
INSERT INTO persons_table (AGE, NAME, ADDRESS, WEIGHT, HEIGHT) 
select 18, "Jack Harrs", "55 Albridge St", 155.20, 167.53 from dual
union all
select 53, "Toby Canes", "59 Albridge St", 193.43, 179.11 from dual
union all
Select 24, "Dwayne Right", "74 W Saint St", 183.22, 183.87 from dual
union all
Select 33, "Shelby Johnson", "99 Broad St", 123.50, 158.30 from dual
```

Comment: Is there a way to build this in java?

Comment: Definitely. There are better ways. But I am not working Java since long. But someone will surely help you. I have just tried to show you the sql syntax  to be inserted into oracle.